# Cleaning Changelog tables - Cron Enterprise_Index scheduledCleanup issue

Tags: indexing, magento-1.14, indexer, ee-1.14

Our instance is throwing an error on this cronjob

> PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name ''

The code is pulling empty table name. It seems the reason is because in the function `Enterprise_Index_Model_Cron::_runCleanupAction()` is this code:

```
$this->_getClient()->init($metadata->getTableName());
```

which passes the correct table names as they are in the database (with prefix "mage_"), but then in the underlying method `Enterprise_Mview_Model_Client::init($name)` it does this...

```
public function init($name)
{
    $tableName = $this->_factory->getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($name);
    $this->_metadata = $this->_factory->getModel('enterprise_mview/metadata')
        ->load($tableName, 'table_name');
    if (!$this->_metadata->getId()) {
        $this->_metadata->setTableName($tableName);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

It gets a new table name using
`$tableName = $this->_factory->getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($name);`
which returns the same table name string only with a duplicated prefix e.g. "mage_mage_enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect". The code then cannot instantiate the model afterwards on this faulty table name.. This seems like a Magento core issue, no? Has Magento addressed this, or what would be the proper way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading the most recent version of Magento 1 EE (1.14.3.9) and found they coded this differently in a way that does not cause the error I'm experiencing. In the "Client.php" file, there is an added method

```
public function initByTableName($tableName)
{
    $this->_metadata = $this->_factory->getModel('enterprise_mview/metadata')
        ->load($tableName, 'table_name');
    if (!$this->_metadata->getId()) {
        $this->_metadata->setTableName($tableName);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Note it does not process the parameter with `$this->_factory->getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName()`. and then in the "Cron.php", they use this new method in `_runCleanupAction()` ..

```
protected function _runCleanupAction(Enterprise_Mview_Model_Metadata $metadata)
{
    $this->_getClient()->initByTableName($metadata->getTableName());
    try {
        $this->_getClient()->execute('enterprise_mview/action_changelog_clear');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_logger->logException($e);
    }
}
```

I ended up modifying these 2 core/enterprise files to match and the cron is working great now.